# How to prove the expression of the non-homogeneous polynomial?

Tags: inequality, polynomials

I am currently studying :"Inequalities,By G. H. HARDY, J. E. LITTLEWOOD, G. PÓLYA", but I am having difficulty proving Theorem 57. Although the book mentions using Theorem 56 and letting $x_m=1-x_1-\ldots-x_{m-1}$, I do not understand how to transform the non-homogeneous condition in Theorem 57 into the homogeneous condition in Theorem 56.  $F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_m)$ is defined as a homogeneous polynomial, for example $F=x^6+y^6+z^6+u^6+v^6+w^6-6 x y z u v w$.

Could anyone please provide some assistance? I would greatly appreciate any proofs or detailed hints that can be provided. Thanks!

[image: Text]

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$, $y$, $z$, $u$, $v$ and $w$ be non-negatives and $x+y+z+u+v+w\leq1$.

Also, let $a=1-x-y-z-u-v-w.$

Thus, $F=x^6+y^6+z^6+u^6+v^6+w^6-6xyzuvw+\frac{1}{121}>0$ and we obtain:
$$F=x^6+y^6+z^6+u^6+v^6+w^6-6xyzuvw+\frac{1}{121}(x+y+z+u+v+w+a)^6,$$ but the coefficient before $xyzuvw$ is equal to
$$-6+\frac{720}{121}<0.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i understand.  I was previously confused about the non-homogeneous parts of the polynomial when substituting $\sum x_i=1$ for $x_m=1-x_1-\cdots-x_{m-1}$, which is equivalent to $\sum x_i=1$ when $x \geqq 0, \quad \sum x>0$. However, the condition for Theorem 56 is $x \geqq 0, \quad \sum x>0$. I was puzzled at that time. Now, through your proof, I remember that since $F$ is already homogeneous, $x \geqq 0, \quad \sum x>0, \sum x_i=1$ and $x \geqq 0, \quad \sum x>0$ are equivalent. This naturally allows me to use the conclusion of Theorem 56. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Yilin Cheng You are welcome!